# Pivot Column names and 1 specified row's values into 2 columns

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have a table that stores the results with the metabolite names as the column names.  Each row is id'd by an accession number.

```
id    accession_number metabolite1 metabolite2 ... meatbolite77
1     000001            50          0                32
2     000002            0           38               0
```

I would like to create a temporary global table that has two columns. The first column would have the names of the metabolites and the second would have all of the values for a specified accession_number.  The name of the table would be the accession number and Results (##000001Results)

```
id    Metabolite    Results
1     Metabolite1  50
2     Metabolite2  0
...
77    Metabolite77 32
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process of changing columns into rows is called **UNPIVOTING**.

If you need only two column (Metabolite name and result as mentioned in the question), you can simply use `UNPIVOT`:

```
select Metabolite, Results
from your_table t
unpivot (
    Results for 
        Metabolite in (
            Metabolite1,
            . . .
            Metabolite77
        )
) as x;
```

If you want to get the IDs too, then use `OUTER APPLY` like this:

```
select x.*
from t outer apply ( 
    values 
        (1, 'Metabolite1', metabolite1),
        ...
        (77, 'Metabolite77', metabolite77)
) x (id, Metabolite, Results)
```

Comment: `^1` can you help me here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41932151/how-to-get-ids-of-4-distinct-values-combination-of-2-keys

Comment: Thank you.  Is there a way to dynamically add the column names instead of having to add each metabolite in the query? I'd like to use this in a stored procedure.  If I add metabolites to the results table I want the query to pick up the new metabolites.

Comment: @Johnny I think you can use Dynamic SQL for this purpose. Just look it up on the google and you'll find plenty of resources on this

Answer (score 1):

I like to do this with `outer apply` and `values`:

```
select v.id, v.metabolite, v.results
from t outer apply
     (values (1, 'metabolite1', metabolite1),
             (2, 'metabolite2', metabolite2),
             . . .
     ) v(id, metabolite, results)
where t.accession_number = @accession_number;
```