# How to get Ids of 4 distinct values ( combination of 2 keys )

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I got table like below

```
mysql> select * from tb_dts;
+----+------+------+
| Id | key1 | key2 |
+----+------+------+
|  1 |    1 |    1 |
|  2 |    1 |    1 |
|  3 |    1 |    1 |
|  4 |    2 |    1 |
|  5 |    2 |    1 |
|  6 |    2 |    1 |
|  7 |    2 |    1 |
|  8 |    1 |    2 |
|  9 |    1 |    2 |
| 10 |    1 |    2 |
| 11 |    1 |    2 |
| 12 |    1 |    2 |
| 13 |    3 |    1 |
| 14 |    3 |    1 |
| 15 |    3 |    1 |
| 16 |    3 |    1 |
| 17 |    2 |    2 |
| 18 |    2 |    2 |
| 19 |    2 |    2 |
| 20 |    2 |    3 |
| 21 |    2 |    3 |
| 22 |    2 |    3 |
| 23 |    3 |    2 |
| 24 |    3 |    2 |
| 25 |    3 |    2 |
| 26 |    3 |    2 |
+----+------+------+
26 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I take distinct values like this, used in some application pagination

```
mysql> select distinct key1,key2 from tb_dts limit 0,4;
+------+------+
| key1 | key2 |
+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |
|    1 |    2 |
|    2 |    1 |
|    2 |    2 |
+------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select distinct key1,key2 from tb_dts limit 4,4;
+------+------+
| key1 | key2 |
+------+------+
|    2 |    3 |
|    3 |    1 |
|    3 |    2 |
+------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Through `group_concat` I get Ids as well but, I want to use this Ids in `WHERE Field IN` clause like  `where somefield IN ( ..here my Ids goes...)`

```
mysql> select key1,key2,group_concat(Id) from tb_dts group by key1,key2 limit 0,4;
+------+------+------------------+
| key1 | key2 | group_concat(Id) |
+------+------+------------------+
|    1 |    1 | 1,2,3            |
|    1 |    2 | 8,9,10,11,12     |
|    2 |    1 | 4,5,6,7          |
|    2 |    2 | 17,18,19         |
+------+------+------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select key1,key2,group_concat(Id) from tb_dts group by key1,key2 limit 4,4;
+------+------+------------------+
| key1 | key2 | group_concat(Id) |
+------+------+------------------+
|    2 |    3 | 20,21,22         |
|    3 |    1 | 13,14,15,16      |
|    3 |    2 | 23,24,25,26      |
+------+------+------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

But How do I put this in `WHERE Fieldname IN` clause ?

I need something like this, as my `tb_dts` contains more that **30 million** reocrds, and `15` fields in real, I can't use `ID BETWEEN min_id and max_id`

For processing first 4 unique combination values I need

```
select * from tb_dts where Id IN (1,2,3,8,9,10,11,12,4,5,6,7,17,18,19  )
```

For processing next 4 unique combination values I need Ids in my application, so in short I want to have below mentioned Ids in my `where Field IN` clause

```
select * from tb_dts where Id IN (20,21,22,13,14,15,16,23,24,25,26 )
```

**Here is structure of my table**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tb_dts`;
CREATE TABLE `tb_dts` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `key1` int(11) DEFAULT '-99',
  `key2` int(11) DEFAULT '-99',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  KEY `main` (`key1`,`key2`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=27 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

LOCK TABLES `tb_dts` WRITE;
INSERT INTO `tb_dts` VALUES (1,1,1),(2,1,1),(3,1,1),(4,2,1),(5,2,1),(6,2,1),(7,2,1),(8,1,2),(9,1,2),(10,1,2),(11,1,2),(12,1,2),(13,3,1),(14,3,1),(15,3,1),(16,3,1),(17,2,2),(18,2,2),(19,2,2),(20,2,3),(21,2,3),(22,2,3),(23,3,2),(24,3,2),(25,3,2),(26,3,2);
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

**As you can see here, it gives first found Id for each distinct combination value**

```
mysql> select Id from tb_dts group by key1,key2 limit 0,4;
+----+
| Id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  8 |
|  4 |
| 17 |
+----+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**But I expect all `Ids` which falls within the criteria given, that is nothing but what all IDs falls for below 4 unique value**

```
mysql> select key1,key2 from tb_dts group by key1,key2 limit 0,4;
+------+------+
| key1 | key2 |
+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |  --- 1,2,3
|    1 |    2 |  --- 8,9,10,11,12
|    2 |    1 |  --- 4,5,6,7 
|    2 |    2 |  --- 17,18,19
+------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Expected o/p**

I expect to get `Id` like this for `group by key1,key2 limit 0,4`, so that this can be used in my `WHERE IN` clause.

```
1
2
3
8
9
10
11
12
4
5
6
7
17
18
19
```

Comment: Question is confused Simply do what your `input` and what your expected `output`.

Comment: you are using limit it is correct  but you must add order by Id. So Id will never repeat

Comment: @krishnpatel : did you understand the scenario here ?

Comment: @user3637224 have you try my ans ?

Comment: Can you do a fiddle of your tables sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your immediate problem, you can use `find_in_set` like this:

```
select t.*
from your_table t
where exists (
    select 1 from (
        select group_concat(Id)
        from tb_dts
        group by key1, key2
        order by key1, key2   -- very important when using limit
        limit 0, 4
    ) t2 where find_in_set(t.fieldname, t2.ids) > 0
);
```

Though I am not sure if this is the best way to do what you're doing. Creating strings using group by and then searching in that string will be too slow.

Also, you want to have an index on key1, key2, id columns.

```
create index idx_tb_dts on tb_dts (key1, key2, id);
```

Can try this:

```
select t.*
from your_table t
where exists (
    select 1
    from tb_dts t1
    inner join (
        select distinct key1, key2
        from tb_dts
        order by key1, key2
        limit 0, 4
    ) t2 on t1.key1 = t2.key1
    and t1.key2 = t2.key2
    where t1.id = t.fieldname
);
```

You should understand that the group by or distinct part can be heavy on performance. It will be much better if there was a separate table containing unique key1, key2 with a unique index on them.

```
create table the_keys_table(
    key1 int not null,
    key2 int not null,
    primary key (key1, key2)
);
```

Then you could replace the tb_dts in below with that table like this:

```
select key1, key2       -- no distinct or group by needed.
from the_keys_table
order by key1, key2
limit 0, 4
```

Your final query becomes:

```
select t.*
from your_table t
where exists (
    select 1
    from tb_dts t2
    where (key1, key2) in (
        select key1, key2
        from the_keys_table
        order by key1, key2
        limit 0, 4
    ) and t1.id = t.fieldname
);
```

Comment: `^1` wow this is amazing, thanks for your valuable response, this seems working, I will let you know if theres any problem

Comment: but I still did not get expected o/p for given input

Comment: can you give me expected output, join does not help to speedup only ID can I think

Comment: if I do join like as you suggested, it has to scan all 30 million rows, but If I get IDs then it will be faster

Comment: The thing is 30 million records *are* going to take some time to manipulate. Also, you should post a question with schema and index details on dba.stackexchange.com . they can help you more on the performance aspects. My guess is that the indexes are not being used and its doing full table scan. Can you post execution plan of the query you are using in the question using EXPLAIN?

Comment: See I have index KEY `main` (`key1`,`key2`), you can see my table structure above

Comment: It has but query optimizer may not use it if it sees (more like thinks) a better execution path. Please post the execution plan in the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134442/discussion-between-user3637224-and-gurv).

Answer (score 0):

you question seems a little confusing but from my understand if what you want is to use the ids in a `WHERE field IN clause` you can make use of subqueries. So in your case where you had `select key1,key2,group_concat(Id) from tb_dts group by key1,key2 limit 4,4;` that can simply become

```
select field 
from table_name 
where id IN 
  (select group_concat(Id) 
   from tb_dts group by key1,key2 limit 4,4)
```

You can find google subqueries to find out more. Let me know what you think about this approach. Hopefully this could be a step.

Comment: With above one `MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'`, so you need to correct like `where ID in( select * ( select group_concat(Id) 
   from tb_dts group by key1,key2 limit 4,4 ) as q )` , sorry it does not work `group_concat` can't help here, that is the reason why I expected o/p Ids in row not as string

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
select  *
    from  tb_dts
    where  Id IN (
        SELECT  r2.Ids from
                  ( SELECT  group_concat(Id) Ids
                    from  tb_dts as r1
                    group by  r1.key1,r1.key2
                    limit  4,4
                  ) r2 
                 );
```

Comment: This will not work, `Every derived table must have its own alias`, `group_concat` inside `where IN` clause will not work this way

Comment: @user3637224 can you try now

Comment: It won't work because there is only item in the `IN` clause, and it is a string `"8,9,10,11,12"`.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:  Abandon the pagination scheme you envision.  Instead, paginate on `key`, not "4 rows per page".

Step 2:  "Remember where you left off".  If the first page has all the pairs for key1 = 1 or 2, then the second page starts with the next value after key1 = 2.

Now the query becomes much more efficient since it is over a "range" of `key1` values.  Currently, it must build the entire output before it can paginate!

[*More*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/pagination-optimization/) discussion of pagination without using `OFFSET`.